# Should I repeat the "is" here?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> It **is** used very frequently and **is** idiomatic.

Or

> It **is** used very frequently and **idiomatic.**

Should I repeat the auxiliary verb **is** in this context?

Are there any rules for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would repeat 'is'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

> It is used very frequently and idiomatic.

It will be taken as

> It is used very frequently and is used very idiomatic.

That is incorrect.  Therefore you need to repeat "is"

The reason is that the two phrases "is used very frequently" and "is idiomatic" are not parallel. The word "is" is an auxiliary verb in the first, and a main verb in the second.

Comment: "You are great and are regarded as one of the best teachers." Is the sentence correct, sir?

Comment: Yes, grammatically correct.  (And please don't use "sir".  I'm nobody's senior just for speaking English)